# Limit $\lim_{t\to 0} \frac{1}{t}\int_0^tf(x)dx$

Tags: integration, limits

Let $f$ is continuous on $[0,1]$with $f(0)=1$.

Let $$g(t)=\frac{1}{t}\int_0^tf(x)dx$$.
Then I am getting $$\lim_{t\to 0}g(t)=1$$. Is it correct?
As I took 3 examples for $f(x)$ and they are $\cos x,e^x,x+1$.For each $f$ I get limit as $1$.But I don't have proper justification for that.Please help me understand this problem.

Comment: Do you know Newton leibnitz theorem

Comment: You could apply L'Hospitals rule here since the numerator (integral) and denominator (t) both approach zero making it indeterminate. You just have to use the fundamental theorem for the numerator

Comment: You can use L'Hospitals rule on the general definition of $g(t)$ and apply Newton-Leibnitz rule to evaluate the derivative of the definite integral.

Answer (score 1):

Let $F(x)$ be the primitive of $f(x)$ on $[0,1]$.

Then we have
$$
\lim_{t\to 0} g(t) = \lim_{t\to 0} \frac{\int_0^t f(t) dt}{t} \overset{(*)}{=} \lim_{t\to 0}\frac{\frac{d}{dt} \int_0^t f(t) dt}{\frac{d}{dt} t} =\lim_{t\to 0}\frac{\frac{d}{dt} (F(t) - \overbrace{F(0)}^{constant})}{1}  =\lim_{t\to 0}\frac{f(t)}{1} = f(0) = 1
$$
$(*)$ Applying L'hopital rule because we have a form "$0/0$".

Comment: what does CST mean

Comment: @SakethMalyala I mean it is simply a constant that will disappear under differentiation : $\frac{d}{dt} cst = 0$. I edited to make it more clear.

Comment: oh okay! thanks

Answer (score 1):

$\displaystyle g(t) = \frac{\displaystyle \int_0^t f(x)\,dx}{t}$

$\displaystyle \lim_{t \to 0} g(t) = \lim_{t \to 0} \frac{\displaystyle \int_0^t f(x)\,dx}{t}$.

Direct evaluation gives $\displaystyle \frac{0}{0}$.

Using L'hopital and Second Fundamental Theorem of Calculus

We get $\displaystyle \lim_{t \to 0} \frac{f(t)}{1}=\frac{1}{1}=\boxed{1}$

Answer (score 0):

If you want a proof using basic techniques:

For any given $\epsilon >0$, take $T>0$ such that when $|x|<T$, $|f(x)-f(0)| < \epsilon$. Now, for all $0< t < T$.

$\begin{align}
\left| \frac{1}{t} \int_0^t f(x) \ dx - f(0) \right| &= \left| \frac{1}{t} \int_0^t f(x) \ dx - \frac{1}{t}\int_0^t f(0) \ dx \right|\\
&= \left| \frac{1}{t} \int_0^t (f(x) - f(0)) \ dx\right|\\
&\le  \frac{1}{t} \int_0^t \left|f(x) - f(0)\right| \ dx\\
&< \epsilon.
\end{align}$

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

This is the fundamental theorem of calculus: the limit is the (right) derivative at $0$ of the function
$$
F(t)=\int_0^t f(x)\,dx
$$
so it is $f(0)$.

If you want to use the mean value theorem, for every $t>0$ there exists $c_t$ with $0<c_t<t$ and
$$
\int_0^t f(x)\,dx=tf(c_t)
$$
so
$$
\lim_{t\to0}\frac{1}{t}\int_0^tf(x)\,dx=\lim_{t\to0}f(c_t)=f(0)
$$